# Save MVC dropdownlist item in database using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor

I am completely new to the MVC architecure and need help with saving a dropdownlist chosen item in a database. Basically for every Project Model on its Create View I need to have a Dropdown list in which I need to pick an istance of Client (Name of client is displayed in the Dropdonwlist). Based on the chosen client the ClientID should be linked to Project object instance in database upon Post method (as a foreign key).

GET part to display `Create` and populate `Dropdownlist` works, POST is what is torturing me.

This is my Project Model:

```
    public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Budget { get; set; }
    public string BusinessCase { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
    }
}
```

This is my Client Model:

```
    public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int VAT { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my CreateProject ViewModel (some of the attributes might be not needed - I just tried a lot of approaches already...)

```
public class CreateProjectViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Budget { get; set; }
    public string BusinessCase { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller GET method for Create (To populate the dropdownlist with Select values from Client table):

```
   public IActionResult Create()
    {


        var clients = _context.Client.Select(r => r.Name);
        var viewmodel = new CreateProjectViewModel
        {
            Clients = new SelectList(clients)
        };
        
        return View(viewmodel); 

    }
```

And Finally, this is is the Create View using the CreateProjectViewModel:

```
@model ProjectPortfolioApp.ViewModels.CreateProjectViewModel
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    }



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control label col-md-2" })
                **@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientId, Model.Clients, "---Select Client---", new { @class = "form-control" })**
            </div>
```

The above code works fine for displaying the Dropdown elements as expected (Name of the client) using `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Clients { get; set; }`.  What I am struggling with is the POST part where I receive error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. When I post `model => model.ClientId` If I pass here basically anyhing else e.g `model => model.Name` there is no error only the Client ID is not succesfully posted in database (obviously).

Here is the snippet of HTTP Post which is most probably wrong:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateProjectViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var project = new Project() { Name = model.Name, ClientId = model.ClientId, Budget = model.Budget, BusinessCase = model.BusinessCase, StartDate = model.StartDate, FinishDate = model.FinishDate };
            _context.Add(project);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
       
        return View();

        
    }
```

Can anyone look at my code and help me identify:

- Is my GET Create constructed fine to serve the purpose of POST Create
- What should be passed in @Html.DropDownListFor as valid parameters to
  avoid the error?
- What should the HTTP Post Create look like?

I looked in dozens of threads, unfortunately nothing helped. Really any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the constructor for SelectList that tells what is the ValueField to be used in the SelectList. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_ If you use the Browser Tools (F12) and inspect the DropdownList showed did you see the value or there is just the text field?

Comment: Hello Steve, when inspecting the page its looks like this:                                     <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ClientId field is required." id="ClientId" name="ClientId"><option value="">---Select Client---</option>
<option>Alza</option>
<option>BNP Paribas</option>
<option>Siemens</option>
<option>CZC</option>
<option>CZU</option>
<option>Coca Cola</option>
</select>

Comment: It should be something like this  _<option value="1">Winter</option>_  Try the constructor in my posted link and pass the name for the field with the value and the name of the field with the description from the Client class

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really worked. Now the HTML after inspect looks like <option value="6">Coca Cola</option> and is stored correctly in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix the action

```
public IActionResult Create()
{

 var clients = _context.Client
           .Select(r =>  new SelectListItem{ Value= r.ClientId.ToString(), Text= r.Name)
           .ToList();

        var viewmodel = new CreateProjectViewModel
        {
            Clients = clients
             .... another properties
        };
        
        return View(viewmodel); 

    }
```

and view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientId, @Model.Clients, "---Select Client---", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Hello Serge, Thanks for sharing the fixed code snippet, this really worked, now values are correctly stored in DB. You really saved me, thanks again.